# Identificar se é blog e ocultar div - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, blog, css-display

Coloquei uma div chamada "imagem_topo" e quero que ela tenha a propriedade `display: none` quando for a página do blog, produto woocommerce ou post. Já tentei colocar no functions.php, no header.php, na page.php e nada funciona.
O que estou fazendo de errado e onde devo colocar o código?

Segue função:

```
function hidediv() {
if(is front_page() && is_home() || is_single() || is_product() ) {
        document.getElementsById("imagem_topo").style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: Oi, [Emerson][1]. Como você está misturando Javascript com PHP, presumo que não tenha muita intimidade com ambos e com ofender , tenho duas perguntas: 1) você é leigo ou posso me aprofundar em alguns pontos de PHP, se necessário? 2) Qual tema está usando, você consegue editar o CSS dele?

Comment: Então eu pensei no código abaixo: